# How to show decimal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Looking for solution to apply decimal for this function .

The function is working very well, unfortunately it completely breaks when I use it with a decimal value.

```
$(function(){
    var value1 = 0;
    var PercenTage = 83.5;
    var span1 = $('#val2');
    var interval1 = setInterval(function(){
        span1.text(++value1);
        if (value1 === PercenTage) {
            clearInterval(interval1);   
            clearInterval(interval2);
            interval1 = null;
            interval2 = null;
        }
    }, 30); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/SGS8h/

Comment: [**jQuery is a JavaScript library**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/187073)

Comment: Try `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`

Comment: or  `Math.round`. But I think that's the right direction.

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks let me try :)

Comment: add increment like `value1 = value1 + 0.1` .. or  `Math.ceil`

Comment: @rab The increment looks fine as it is

Comment: @dystroy doesn't stop increasing when  `var PercenTage = 83.5;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PercenTage.toFixed(0)` if you want int in the end... and @Kasyx correctly pointed out the `>=` works for you instead of `===` ; )

And if you want to show decimal value just do that:

```
    if (value1 >= PercenTage) {
        span1.text(PercenTage);
        clearInterval(interval1);   
        clearInterval(interval2);
        interval1 = null;
        interval2 = null;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SGS8h/3/

Comment: The result expecting same value even if the value decimal  `PercenTage = 83.5;` result `83.5%` like this

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil you don't want to display the `%` sign ? Or I didn't understand you

Comment: exactly :) I was looking for this solution. thank very very much bro. Unfortunately I lost my reputation because of this question :( 

  thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

Use if `(value1 >= PercenTage)`  instead of `(value1 === PercenTage)`

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGS8h/1/

Comment: result shows like this **84%** for `var PercenTage = 83.5;`

Comment: Yes, additional update is needed, give me a while

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time :)

Comment: what is the result that you want?

Comment: @thinklinux result should be with decimal when `PercenTage` value decimal.

   unfortunately people are down voting my question I don't know why :(

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Like this? [**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/SGS8h/2/)

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil thinklinux found solution and merged into one correct.

Comment: @Kasyx Yes, finally got the answer. any way I put upvote for you both, thanks for your valuable time